# Create Force.com project from DE Org

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I have Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) installed and the Force.com plugin installed.  I've been able to connect to a Development Sandbox from within Eclipse.  However, I cannot connect to my DE Org environment.  Is this possible using the Force.com plugin for Eclipse?  Or can you only connect to non-DE Org environments from within Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first "Environment" option when you create a Force.com project is "Production/Developer Edition" and using that yes you can connect to a DE Org.

Have you double checked the credentials you are using including the security token? What error are you seeing?

Comment: With "Production/Developer Edition" selected, I get back this error: Unable to connect to hostname 'www.salesforce.com': Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.  I don't see an option in my DE Org where I can generate a token, so I'm using a valid username/password that works when I log into the DE Org via my browser.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Log in via your browser and follow these instructions to have a new security token emailed to you https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_security_token.htm&language=en_US. You can't connect from the Force.com IDE without a security token because the underlying APIs used require a security token.

Comment: I'm new to the platform, so I hadn't realized where that option was displayed for a DE org.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MichaelSobczak You can also whitelist your ip if your token changes a lot.  Might have to check with your admin to see if they will let you do that

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "Unable to connect to hostname 'www.salesforce.com': Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out",

make sure Security Token Field is blank and the password field has YOURpasswordYOURsecuritytoken